# SL3 Nav framework + MVVM ligh

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, mvvm, navigation, mvvm-light

Thanks for taking time to read through my question. Any guidance is really appreciated.

I am using SL3 Navigation  framework in my LOB application. I m currently using MVVM Light as the framework guidance.

I have a datagrid consisting of employees and when the "user" clicks on "employee id link" in the datagrid, i am transferring the user to "Edit Page". I would like to transfer the "employee id" as query parameter to "edit page".

The issue here is: I can access the query parameter in the EditStaffView.xaml.cs - which i don't want to do.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("staffcode"))
        {
            string title = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["staffcode"];
        }
    }
```

I would like to retrieve the query parameter in my viewmodel and based on the query parameter, i will perform certain operations. When the constructor is called I would like the "view" to pass the staffid as shown below

```
    public EditStaffViewModel(int staffId)
    {
        LoadData(staffId);
    }
```

I am constructing my hyperlink buttons in the datagrid dyanmically as shown below:

staffListingModel.HyperlinkNavigationUri = string.Format("{0}{1}",                                                                               NavigationUri.DataEntryEditStaff,"?staffcode={" +                               staffListingModel.StaffCode + "}");

and XAML looks

***HyperlinkButton
Content="{Binding StaffCode,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                         NavigateUri="{Binding HyperlinkNavigationUri}">                                        HyperlinkButton***

Any idea how to do this ??

Thanks for the help.
Murari

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with the Querystring.
since your are using MVVM Light Toolkit. Take a look at the Messenger and take advantage of the public an subscriber pattern. Similar to the PRISM Eventaggregator.

Send out the "Staffcode" and subscribe in every viewmodel which needs to take advantage of it. You can also send the whole employe object.

Messenger.Default.Send(selectedEmployee);

Messenger.Default.Subscribe(this);
Refer to this link for Messinging:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/03/16/whatrsquos-new-in-mvvm-light-v3.aspx
Eventaggregator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707867.aspx

In case of deep linking and navigation in combination with mvvm you have to think different. Communication between ViewModels should be done by Messenging. Eventaggregator or Messenger.

Hope this helps...